# Codeigniter method not found in class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just started to learn CodeIgniter. I have some background in PHP but not in OOP. So I've downloaded the CI from their website and started to follow the user guide but I faced some problems like this

> Message: Undefined property: News_model::$load
>
> Filename: models/news_model.php
>
> Line Number: 7

On that line is the `__construct()` function

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->database();
}
```

Also in the next function `db field not found in class 'News model'` and `method 'result_array' not found in class...`

```
public function get_news($slug = FALSE)
{
    if ($slug === FALSE)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('news');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

**I know that this is very basic but I'm a bit lost right now**. I'll be glad if someone can explain or at least point me to another good tutorial/s that I can learn. Here is the full `class News_model`

```
class News_model extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->database();
}

public function get_news($slug = FALSE)
{
    if ($slug === FALSE)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('news');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));
    return $query->row_array();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Models **should** extend the `CI_Model` class.

```php
class News_model extends CI_Model { /* ... */ }
```

---

However, using Controllers you need to call `__construct` method of `CI_Controller` class when you override the `__construct` method:

```php
class News extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Call CI_Controller construct method first.
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->database();
    }
}
```

Since you're overriding the `__construct()` method within the inheritor class, you should call the parent constructor at first.

Otherwise, when the controller is initializing, you'll lose [`Loader` and `Core`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/core/Controller.php#L37-L54) class and `$this->load` will never work.

Comment: Yes, is working like this. Also when I write `CI_Model`.. not `CI_Controler`.. clearly is my fault.

Comment: @slsv Should I delete the answer? I'm confused :)

Comment: I think is ok to stay. Is good for me because I learn something new. Mat be will be helpful for someone else also.

Comment: One more thing, can you suggest good tutorial or place to learn CI or their user guide is good enought?

Comment: @slsv IMHO the official user guide is well explained and would be a good starting point. However you can find good articles about CI on nettuts+

Comment: Thank's again. I'll continue with official guide and then will see tuts+.

Answer (score 3):

sorry but:

```
class News_model extends CI_Controller {...}
```

???

Comment: Ah, my mistake and yes in the guide is `CI_Model`.. not `CI_Controler`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, user2883814 is right, every model in CodeIgniter must extend only CI_Model class.
So it should look like this:

```
class News_model extends CI_Model
```

Then you should load your model to controller for using.

By the way models aren't used in CodeIgniter so often, and you can use only controllers and views instead.

Comment: Thank you for replay. Now I saw my mistake.